# Optimal Conditional Distribution for Minimising Information-Theoretic Expression

Tags: optimization, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, logarithm, derivative

Consider two countable sets $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$. I aim to find the conditional distribution $P_{Y|X}$ that minimizes the following expression for any $x \in \mathcal{X}$

$$\sum_y P_{Y|X}(y|x) \log \frac{ P(y|x)^{1+a}  }{W(y|x) \left(\sum_{\bar{x}} Q(\bar{x}) P_{Y|X}(y|\bar{x})   \right)^a   } ,$$

where $a$ is some positive constant, $W$ represents some conditional distribution, and $Q$ is the marginal distribution of $X$. I attempted to apply variations of the log-sum inequality, but I encountered difficulties in obtaining a useful result. Additionally, I don't believe it's feasible to solve it by computing derivatives. The solution should be expressed in terms of $Q$ and $W$ and $a$.